# Delphi xe3 vcl to firemonkey array issue

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, firemonkey-fm2

When converting from VCL to Firemonkey in Delphi, I have the following issue:
In VCL I have the following array:
Tcarray=array[1..$04000000] of Tcoordinate; - This works fine.

However, declaring the same array in Firemonkey I get an exception about stack overflow at 0x00..
My only solution so far is to minimize the array to [1..40000].

Why is this?  Any solution?

The VCL code is as follow

```
unit ptypes;

interface
uses windows,vcl.Graphics,Vcl.Imaging.jpeg,Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg,system.Types;

type
Tcoordinate=packed record
x,y:double;
end;

Tcarray=array[1..$04000000] of Tcoordinate;

Tpoly=packed record
   n:longint;
   c:Tcarray;
end;
```

It will be called like this:

```
procedure TForm12.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   poly:Tpoly;
begin
with poly do
begin
    c[1].x:=100; c[1].y:=100;
    c[2].x:=400; c[2].y:=100;
    c[3].x:=400; c[3].y:=400;
    c[4].x:=250; c[4].y:=550;
    c[5].x:=100; c[5].y:=400;
    n:=5;
end;
```

This works fine in VCL but in FM it breaks with the following error:  "Project FMtest.exe raised exception class $C00000FD with message 'stack overflow at 0x00af69e7'.

Comment: You need to [edit] your post to add the actual code (the full declarations of the type, the code that declares the actual array, and the code that uses it), along with the exact error message you're getting with the exception, for both versions of the code if you want us to help. A vague description of the problem is probably not going to be enough, because what you're describing shouldn't be happening.

Comment: edited as required.  Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stack overflow occurs because you are creating a very large local variable `poly` (of 1.073.741.828 bytes ¡¡¡¡) and the stack (the place where the local variables are stored) has a limited size.

You can avoid this issue redeclarating your types in this way

```
PCArray=^Tcarray;
Tcarray=array[1..$04000000] of Tcoordinate;


Tpoly=packed record
   n:longint;
   c:PCArray;
end;
```

And use like so

```
var
   poly   : Tpoly; //now poly only uses 8 bytes of the stack space
   points : integer;
begin
  points:=5;
  GetMem(poly.c,sizeof(Tcoordinate)*points);
  try
    with poly do
    begin
      c[1].x:=100; c[1].y:=100;
      c[2].x:=400; c[2].y:=100;
      c[3].x:=400; c[3].y:=400;
      c[4].x:=250; c[4].y:=550;
      c[5].x:=100; c[5].y:=400;
      n:=points;
    end;
  finally
    FreeMem(poly.c);
  end;
end;
```